# Git merge 2 branches from 2 different git repositories and having empty conflicts

Tags: git, merge

I have 2 repos, almost identical in content, but they are different git repos, different commits.

I want to merge a branch from repo A onto repo B, but when I do that I have a lot of empty conflicts. This meaning, conflicted files without `<<<<<` `>>>>>`, both files in both branches are identical, but in conflict as per git.

Of course that I can just `git checkout --theirs fileX && git add fileX` and continue with my life **but** I have literally 1000 conflicts, where 50 are real conflicts and 950 are this kind of conflict. So, going through all 1000 conflicts would take me an eternity.

**How can I merge both branches ignoring this "empty conflicts" which are not real conflicts? It's like git is saying "it's a conflict because the files A and B are different" but in reality the contents are the same.**

What I'm doing:

```
git remote add otherRepo file://...
git fetch --all
git merge -Xignore-all-space otherRepo/otherBranch
```

I thought of a script iterating on the **"conflicts"** checking if there is a conflict or not, and if not, git add it.

But I want to know if this workaround can be avoided.

git status:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

new file: fileA
new file: fileB
[a lot of new file: file...]

Unmerged paths:
 (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

 both added: fileW
 both added: fileX
 both added: fileY
 [a lot of both added: file...]
```

No modifications or anything else, all `new files` and `both added`.

Comment: Does your white space configuration is on?

Comment: Yes, actually I merge with `-Xignore-all-space`, I omitted it in the explanation to make it clearer

Comment: what is the output of "git status"? Are the conflicts because of file permission differences? (-c core.filemode=false)

Comment: Added status. Both repos are in the same file system, so I don't think that's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you have tried to merge with `-Xignore-all-space`
and it still not working try this out:

```
git merge -Xignore-space-change
```

Comment: I'll try but doesn't `ignore-all-space` "include" `ignore-space-change`? "-Xignore-all-space or -Xignore-space-change. The first option ignores whitespace completely when comparing lines, the second treats sequences of one or more whitespace characters as equivalent."

Comment: It should be but this is more explicit.

Comment: Same result with `ignore-space-change`